# Distributing values into a histogram

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $b_1(n), b_2(n), \ldots, b_k(n)$ be the height of the $k$ bars of a fixed-width histogram with $n$ data points.  Assume $k$ is constant, and $n\geq k$ is an integer which is increasing as we collect new data. Let $d_n$ be the value received at time $n$.  I would like to calculate the height of $b_i(n)$ for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$, with the data uniformly scaled to fit the width.

For example in case $k = 3$ and $n=6$, then each bar $b_i(6)$ will consist of an average of two data values: $$b_1(6) = \frac{1}{2}(d_1 + d_2), \ \ \ b_2(6) = \frac{1}{2}(d_3 + d_4),\ \ \text{and }\  b_3(6) = \frac{1}{2}(d_5 + d_6).$$

Continuing the example with $k=3$, if $n=7$, I think we should set:
$$b_1(7) = \frac{3}{7}d_1+\frac{3}{7}d_2 + \frac{1}{7}d_3 $$
$$b_2(7) = \frac{2}{7}d_3+\frac{3}{7}d_4 + \frac{2}{7}d_5 $$
$$b_3(7) = \frac{1}{7}d_5+\frac{3}{7}d_6 + \frac{3}{7}d_7 $$

The problem is to find a general formula to calculate $b_i(n+1)$ as a function of the constant $k$ and the values $n, d_1, \ldots d_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can follow a guide from an old joke, saying that in order to quickly count sheep in a field we have to count a number of their legs and divide it by four.

Assume that we have the values $c_1,\dots, c_{nk}$ such that
$$c_1=c_2=\dots=c_k=d_1,$$
$$c_{k+1}=c_{k+2}=\dots=c_{2k}=d_2$$
$$\dots,$$
$$c_{(n-1)k+1}= c_{(n-1)k+2}=\dots=c_{nk}=d_n.$$

Then for each $i=1,2,\dots, k$  we have $$nb_i(n)=c_{(i-1)n+1}+c_{(i-1)n+2}+\dots+c_{in}.\label{1}\tag{1}$$

Since the sequence $\{c_t:1\le t\le nk\}$ consists of $n$ blocks of equals values of length $k$ each, we can calculate  $b_i(n)$,
in terms of $d_j$ as follows. The expression \eqref{1} starts from the last $k-r$ values $d_{j+1}$ of the $j+1$-th block for some $0<r<k$ and $0\le j$, then it has a contiguous sequence (possibly, empty) of complete blocks from $j+2$-th to $j’$-th for some $j’$, and finally it has $0<r’<k$ values $d_{j’+1}$ of the beginning of $j’+1$-th block. From the above we have  $(i-1)n=jk+r$ and $in=j'k+r'$, so $$nb_i(n)=(k-r)d_{j+1}+k\sum_{\ell=j+2}^{j'} d_\ell+r'd_{j'+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  It's hard to understand where the last line comes from.  It does not seem to be directly justified from what is above, which is itself clear.

Comment: @kels-19 I skipped technical details. Also I checked the final formula by your example $k=3$ and $n=7$, and it fits.

Comment: Cool that it fits a specific example.   I tried some others and it fits also.  But to help me convince myself or understand why it may work in general, I would love the technical details.

Comment: @kels-19 I updated the answer,  adding details. Sorry for the delay.